# What is the difference between UML Data profile and ER model?

Tags: database, database-design, uml, entity-relationship, diagramming

I have been asked this question and even after a lot of research, I cannot find the answer.

When I design a database using Entity relationship (ER) and then re-draw it as UML class model (extended with Data modeling profile for UML), what are the differences and how both models can be (in their way) useful for db developer? With regard to multiplicity, foreign keys..

Answer (score 1):

- UML class - model doesn't support views, stored procedures, triggers and databases elements. ER does.
- There is NO data modelling profile over class diagram in UML. [look](http://www.omg.org/google-search-results2.htm?cx=partner-pub-9572230613594886:9khir1su9st&cof=FORID:10&ie=ISO-8859-1&q=data%20modelling&sa=Search&siteurl=www.uml.org/&ref=&ss=2774j641252j14) a search. It seams, it is a special [feature](http://www.mario-jeckle.de/files/RationalUML-RDB-Profile.pdf) of IBM, but they don't keep to UML.
- We can draw anything on the newly-invented diagram language. But what is the use of it? If you are really interested, study the [pdf](http://www.mario-jeckle.de/files/RationalUML-RDB-Profile.pdf).